# Repeat Unity game Task on android every x hours

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity game that is for Android. I don't have much experience with it, so I wanted to know the way to create mission every four hours.

Right now I just invoke repeating the asynchronic Task to fetch the data from Firebase (it works perfectly fine), but I have doubts about this solution. I'm not sure how it works -> if the user turns off the app, will it be able to send notifications that the mission was created, or the app have to run in the background? 
In case users quit I will store the time in static variable and compare the time when user logs in again.
I was thinking about doing it from the back-end side - Firebase or Playfab -> sending the trigger to start the task every 4 hours, but I'm also not sure how it works -> if the user will have his app turned off, does it mean that he will miss the trigger?

Will greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, you have some options.

Depending on what you're doing, I think your best answer would just be to use Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#listen_for_events

If you really want to wake up your clients to poll data, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client
If you're using the later, you can schedule a cloud function as noted here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

There's a lot more to daisy chain here, so I've tried to pull the relevant bits out of the above samples:

```
// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
var topic = 'four_hours';

export scheduledFunctionPlainEnglish =
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 4 hours').onRun((context) => {
    var message = {
      data: {
        score: '850',
        time: '2:45'
      },
      topic: topic
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
});
```

And on Unity, you'd just subscribe to that topic:

```
Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.Subscribe("four_hours");
Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
```

Finally, It's hard to say what will work exactly right for you given the information you've provided. But, if it is something you'd like each client to poll every 4 hours, I think you're better off writing some native Android code to do it. I'd recommend looking at WorkManager, specifically setting up a periodic work request:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work

You'd want to write a native Java or Kotlin library and access it from Unity. That's more detailed than I think I can get to in a Stack Overflow answer, but I'll point you over to Unity's documentation to do so: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJavaSourcePlugins.html

It's a bit more work, but the idea of "wake up my game every four hours to do a thing" is kind of uncommon. Normally you'd want a push notification whenever something interesting happens (ex: just a cloud message to my client when I receive a gift from a friend or it's my turn), or you'd want want to subscribe to changes in your Realtime Database whenever an interesting thing happens to your game and it's currently running.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! After doing a lot of research and reading you answer I decided it will be much better to use Firebase notifications, push notification every 4 hours, open the app after user clicks on it , go to the login screen and then create the case. What I'm still bit afraid of is the case when user dismiss the notification, because I'm not sure if he will miss the event. On the other hand I think it can be a part of the experiment -> users who ignore the notification will have less cases to solve and will earn less in-game money.